# PostgreSQL - how to unlock table record AFTER shutdown

Tags: postgresql

Sorry I looked for this everywhere but cannot find a working solution :/
I badly needed this for abnormal testing.

What I'm trying to do here is:

1. Insert row in TABLE A
2. Lock this record
3. (At separate terminal) service postgresql-9.6 stop
4. Wait a few moments
5. (At separate terminal) service postgresql-9.6 start
6. "try" to unlock the record by executing "COMMIT;" in the same terminal as #2.

How i did #2 is like this:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE X=Y FOR UPDATE;
```

Problem is that once I did #6, this error shows up:

```
DB=# commit;
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

So when I execute "COMMIT;" again, it only shows:

```
DB=# commit;
WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
COMMIT
```

**Now the record cannot be unlocked.**

I've tried getting the PID of that locking thing, and then execute pg_terminate (or cancel), but it just doesn't work.

```
DB=# select pg_class.relname,pg_locks.* from pg_class,pg_locks where pg_class.relfilenode=pg_locks.relation;
DB=# select pg_terminate_backend(2450);
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
DB=# select pg_cancel_backend(3417);
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

Please help. Does anyone have any ideas? :/
..Or is this even possible?

My specs:

- Postgresql-9.6
- RedHat Linux

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding or three here. Lock state is not persistent.

When you lock a record (or table), the lock is associated with the transaction that took the lock. The transaction is part of the running PostgreSQL session, your connection to the server.

Locks are released at the end of transactions.

Transactions end:

- On explicit `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`;
- When a session disconnects without an explicit `COMMIT` of the open transaction, triggering an implied `ROLLBACK`;
- When the server shuts down, terminating all active sessions, again triggering an implied `ROLLBACK` of all in-progress transactions.

Thus, you have released the lock you took at step 2 when you shut the server down at step 3. The transaction that acquired that lock no longer exists because its session was terminated by server shutdown.

If examine `pg_locks` you'll see how the locked row is present before restart and vanishes after restart.

Comment: I would also add that it is not realistic to expect anything else but the behavior you're seeing for other direct connections to the database. They will be terminated when the database is shut down.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for the information! So basically my end-goal is wrong xD We may need to refine this test. We're planning to create abnormal testing around transactions and locking. Do you have an existing guide on the details of your answer? Or something where we could find those?

Comment: @Bill you have a good point. We will consider that as, like, a point-of-view when we do extremely crazy tests from now on xD

Comment: @thisNeil No references off the top of my head, but start with the PostgreSQL documenation on transactions, concurrency, and isolation. The best stress tests you can run are generally "chaos monkey" style ones where you take your production system and break stuff under it randomly, then see how it behaves.

Comment: @Craig nice. thanks! will definitely look into postgresql documentations.